# BroadcastReceiver does not work when application is in background or killed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, broadcastreceiver

I have created `BroadcastReceiver` where I detect when an incoming call is received on the device.
My code is

```
[BroadcastReceiver()]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" })]
public class MyBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
    //My implementation
    }
}
```

Problem is when the application is not running or killed forcefully, BroadcastReceiver class does not get called. 
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> BroadcastReceiver does not work when application is not in background or killed

You could refer to: [Android Broadcast Receiver not working when the app is killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938411/android-broadcast-receiver-not-working-when-the-app-is-killed), as CommonsWare said:

> Once `onReceive()` returns, if you do not have an activity in the foreground and you do not have a running service, your process importance will drop to what [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/processes/process-lifecycle.html) refers to as a "cached process". Your process is eligible to be terminated at any point. Once your process is terminated, your `BroadcastReceiver` goes away. Hence, your code as written will be unreliable, as your process might be terminated within your 30-second window.

## Solution:

So you could use a `Service` to implement your feature, here is my simple demo:

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new String[] { "com.xamarin.DemoService" })]
public class DemoService : Service
{
    private static DemoReceiver m_ScreenOffReceiver;

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        registerScreenOffReceiver();
        base.OnCreate();
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        UnregisterReceiver(m_ScreenOffReceiver);
        m_ScreenOffReceiver = null;
        base.OnDestroy();
    }

    //From this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592366/the-process-of-the-service-is-killed-after-the-application-is-removed-from-the-a
    public override void OnTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)
    {
        Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(DemoService));
        restartServiceIntent.SetPackage(PackageName);

        PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetService(Application.Context, 1, restartServiceIntent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);
        AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
        alarmService.Set(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtime, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + 1000, restartServicePendingIntent);
        base.OnTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }

    private void registerScreenOffReceiver()
    {
        m_ScreenOffReceiver = new DemoReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.xamarin.example.TEST");
        RegisterReceiver(m_ScreenOffReceiver, filter);
    }
}
```

## Update:

If you need the service run at a higher priority to avoid it be killed, you could try using [Foreground Service](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/part_1_-_started_services/#Foreground_Services). As SushiHangover [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47315432/how-to-run-accelerometer-on-background/47324489#47324489):

As a foreground service it has a higher priority so the OS will consider it last to be killed, it avoids the automatic dozing of your services to save battery in later APIs , etc... The "downside" is the user must be made aware that it is running, thus the requirement to be placed in the notification bar, personally I do not see that as a problem and wish it was a hard requirement for all services.

Answer (score 0):

BroadcastReceiver will not work when the application is killed, you have to use service for that , you can use BroadcastReceiver inside a service to run it even when the app is not running.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Can you please share any example if you have? i am just the beginner to mobile development.